# Deleting specific row from ms word table that contains a specific word

Tags: vba, ms-word, cpu-word

I am having a table in MS Word and trying to delete some specific rows from it. I have a vba script but it deletes rows from all the tables. I just want to delete rows from table number 2. Here is my code:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithSpecifiedText()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With .Tables.Find
    .Text = "Moderate"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Do While Selection.Find.Execute
    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        Selection.Rows.Delete
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

How do I specify the table in it to delete rows that contain **Moderate** in column # 3? I am totally new to VBA. Please help me figure this out

**Updating Requirements**

1. I need to delete all rows that contain Moderate or Empty in column 3
2. I need to sort my tables based on the values in Column 3 which are Critical, High, Moderate
   3.Change the colors of cell3/row as critical, high: red, moderate: orange, low: yellow (If possible.)

I am working on the above tasks but not finding a proper way to do it in MS Word. Is there any extension available or something which can do the task or VBA is better or what? Thanks a lot for your time

**More Question from your script**
How do I remove the row that has no content in Col3 as there is Moderate and Empty? Sorry for being too much dumb,

Comment: First you say «I need to delete all rows that contain Moderate or Empty in column 3», but then you say «I need to sort the rows in order as Critical, High, Moderate, and Low». How do you expect to sort 'Moderate' rows after they've been deleted? See updated code & notes in my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, r As Long, Clr As Long, bFit As Boolean
Const StrFnd As String = "|Moderate|Empty"
Const MyColorOrange As Long = 41215
With ActiveDocument.Tables(2)
  bFit = .AllowAutoFit
  .AllowAutoFit = False
  For r = 1 To UBound(Split(StrFnd, "|"))
    Set Rng = .Range
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = Split(StrFnd, "|")(r)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
      End With
      Do While .Find.Execute
        If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
        If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 3 Then .Rows(1).Delete
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      Loop
    End With
  Next
  For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
    With .Cell(r, 3)
      Select Case Split(.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)
        Case "Critical": Clr = wdColorRed
        Case "High": Clr = MyColorOrange
        Case "Moderate": Clr = wdColorYellow: .Range.Text = "X"
        Case "Low": Clr = wdColorBrightGreen: .Range.Text = "Y"
        Case Else: Clr = wdColorAutomatic: .Range.Text = "Z"
      End Select
      .Row.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Clr
    End With
  Next
  .Sort ExcludeHeader:=True, FieldNumber:=3, SortFieldType:=wdSortFieldAlphanumeric, SortOrder:=wdSortOrderAscending
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "[XYZ]"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Format = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute
      If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
      If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        Select Case .Text
          Case "X": .Text = "Moderate"
          Case "Y": .Text = "Low"
          Case "Z": .Rows(1).Delete
        End Select
      End If
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
  .AllowAutoFit = bFit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With a long table, the Find/Replace should be faster than looping through all rows.

Your additional specifications are ambiguous. Your first specification includes deleting all rows containing 'Moderate' in column 3, but in specifications 2 & 3 you say you want those rows sorted and shaded. Specification 3 introduces cells containing 'Low', but these aren't mentioned in your sorting requirements at specification 2. It's also not apparent what shading 'Critical' should have. It's impossible to code to such inconsistent specifications. If you want to keep the 'Moderate' rows, delete '|Moderate' from:

```
Const StrFnd As String = "|Moderate|Empty"
```

With your additional specifications, looping though all remaining table rows will still be required. See updated code. I've assumed all retained rows require different shading according to whether they're Critical, High, Moderate, or Low. Change the shading specs (i.e. Clr) to suit whatever your real requirements are.

If you want to shade only the conditional cell, rather than the entire row, change:

```
.Row.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Clr
```

to:

```
.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Clr
```

Comment: what if I need to add an OR condition in text?

Comment: and the column contains no value

Comment: Kindly put *all* the conditions in your original post - not in afterthought comments. You need to be especially clear about 'which' column has no value. In any event a Find operation can't find a nothing.

Comment: @macropad I have updated the question again for the **sorting** purpose. please have a look again. Sorry for being too much dumb. I really did not have any idea about this. I was thinking about it like programming in Java. I get a single point and merge it with others but it is much different to that.

Comment: I have started another bounty of worth 100 and will award it to you

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this very easy and straight forward. Try this.

```
sub deleteRowsWithModerate()
Dim T As Table
Dim r As row
'  Set your 2nd Table as the one to be worked on
Set T = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

'iterate over all rows, check if the 3rd cell (= 3rd column) of each row has the desired String in it.
For Each r In T.Rows
  If InStr(r.Cells(3).Range.text, "Moderate") Then r.Delete
Next

End sub
```

Notice that

`If r.Cells(3).Range.text = "Moderate" then`

wont work, because the text of a cells always has a hidden placeholder in it, so the cell-text is like "moderate" & chr(13) & chr(7).

Comment: Why a Function? The whole thing could be done as a Sub...

Comment: Wheather Sub or Function doesn't has effect on the solution though. It was just what i hacked in my Test to solve that problem. As we have no returnvalue we can use a sub instead.

Comment: what If I need to add an OR operator in text? Will this be feasible for a long table? because I am having a long table

Comment: and the column contains no value

Comment: I wonder why my Answer got downrated. Its clear, correct, commented/explained and easy for "the totally new to VBA"-Asker. Really unsatisfying to get that downgrade (esp cause its my first contribution on SO). Enough cries.

What is a "long" table? 20, 200, 2k rows? I tested with ~ 20 rows and didnt experience a lag, so runtime was < 1 second. Test youself if runtime is ok for you. 

For more than one Text triggering delete you can add more lines

`If InStr(r.Cells(3).Range.text, "XYZ") Then r.Delete`

Or you build a collection of values. Depends on number of triggers and lazyness ;)

Comment: I assume you want to delete a row, when cloumn 3 is empty. Then you can use the placeholder i mentioned in my answer and check straight for it:

`If r.Cells(3).Range.text = chr(13) & chr(7) then r.delete`

For explanation: every cells contains always and undeletable set of char13 (Carrage Return) and char 7 (Bell).

Comment: @BenediktWegener it deletes the rows but there is an issue. It is much slower. I am having more than 300 rows and it keeps updating the page and get not responding in moments

Comment: Use the solution from @macropod, it is fast and does all you want. `application.screenupdating = false` does the trick on performance (with every Makro!).

Comment: Functions `return` whereas subs `do`. The above should be re-written as a sub as it returns nothing.

Comment: I rewrote as Sub, gave a proper name to it and added the right empty-cell-placeholder. I like to add to the function/sub-debate that subs are visible in the "Execute-Makro"-Menu for the user. Sometimes you have non-returning-routines wich should NOT be startet by your user manually, just from some other Makrocode. Thats why i use always functions, only if the user is supposed to "see and start" it, i use explicitly subs.  Like to hear your comment on that.